# How do I extract a nested alphanumeric value from a dictionary using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
{
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': '{"message": "data product request creation successful", "id": "a84f04f2539f11eca7ba0e2e68e2041f"}'
}
```

I want to extract the "id" inside the "body" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).
Here is a basic example of how to do what you want:

```
import json

d = {'statusCode': 200, 'body': '{"message": "data product request creation successful", "id": "a84f04f2539f11eca7ba0e2e68e2041f"}'}
body = json.loads(d['body'])

print(body['id'])
# a84f04f2539f11eca7ba0e2e68e2041f
```